# Custom-shaped <div> tags with background images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a popover design. Each popover has a header with a dynamically generated background image on it. The design calls for a pointer at the top of the header, but I cannot think of a way to implement this and maintain the background image. [image: I've attached a screenshot of the design here.]

Here's the current markup, sans pointer:

```
        <div class="popup">
            <header class="popup-header" style="background-image: url(http://thebusstopsherefoundation.com/images/bettis_wave.jpg);">
                <h1>
                    <a class="resourceName" href="" target="_blank"></a>
                </h1>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </header>
            <main class="popup-body">
                <section class="details">
                    <div class="resourceDescription">
                        <p></p>
                    </div><!-- /resource-description-->
                    <div class="attributes">
                    </div><!-- attronites-->
                </section><!-- / details-->
                <section class="organization">
                    <h3>Organization Information</h3>
                    <h2 class="orgName">
                        <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="orgDescription">
                    </div><!-- /orgdescription-->
                </section><!-- /organization-->
            </main>
            <section class="cta">
                <a class="btn" href="" target="_blank">Participate</a>
            </section><!-- cta-->
        </div><!--popup-->
```

Every CSS shape implementation I know requires borders or box shadows, neither of which will apply here. Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Actually put transparency in that part of the image and make it the background of a square?

Comment: Take a look at clipping paths https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ and apply it to the top part as required.

Comment: @TinyGiant Good thinking but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work because of the box-shadow on the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using css clip-path and using a polygon as the parameter. Here is an example:

```
<div class="dialog"></div>
```

And the CSS

```css
.dialog{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d3d0c9;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/Dummy-Text/);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 85% 25%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 85% 25%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog"></div>
```

Browser support is limited to [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) though.

You can play around using this tool : http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Important Note: This only works in Webkit right now (Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.). See the note on caniuse about Firefox/IE/Edge supporting only the url syntax. For browser support, you will need to use an SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `transform`s to accomplish the desired corner effect.  Although the solution is more complicated than the accepted one, it can be implemented on pretty much all modern browsers.  By using several of the `transform` polyfills, the solution can be implemented across the board.

The algorithm behind this solution achieves a corner element via `skewX()` transform that is equally applied on the image (set as a background) and its container, just in different directions (e.g., `-63.43deg` and `63.43deg`, depending on the dimensions of the corner element).  Then the generated corner element is perfectly aligned with the heading's background.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bLbt11a3/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "popup">
    <header>
        <h1>DIY Gardener</h1>
        <div class = "corner-holder">
            <div class = "corner"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.popup {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    height: 240px;
    width: 186px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.popup h1 {
    font: bold 20px/3 Sans-Serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: url(http://thebusstopsherefoundation.com/images/bettis_wave.jpg)
                no-repeat
                -80px -90px/600px;
}

.popup header {
    position: relative;
}

.corner-holder {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.corner-holder .corner,
.corner-holder .corner:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    /* webkit trick to get rid of jagged edges */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.corner-holder .corner {
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: skewX(-63.43deg);
}

.corner-holder .corner:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://thebusstopsherefoundation.com/images/bettis_wave.jpg)
                no-repeat
                -206px -60px/600px;
    transform: skewX(63.43deg);
}
```

Comment: It's quite a bit more markup like this, but until IE supports clip-path or Microsoft just drops IE completely (*oh please Microsoft! Please!!!!*), I don't think clip-path should be used except maybe in browser extensions where it is guaranteed to not have to support IE.

Comment: I completely agree.  Hence, this solution.  clip-path is not nearly as stable of a spec as transforms.  Transforms are available in IE beginning with version 9.  There are some polyfills available for clip-path, but I have not tested any of them.